# Identify the movie where a cartoonist turns into an animation

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I remember a movie, probably italian or some similar latin language, where a cartoonist is slowly transformed into an animated character. It was released, I think, in the same decade as [Who Framed Roger Rabbit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096438/) which is why I remember the combination of live action and animation (not 100% on the timing, though).

So what is the movie, and can I get in on region 2 DVD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're talking about [Volere Volare (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103223/), an italian movie where the main character has a date with a girl, but he's so nervous that he transformes into an animated character.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the film [*Cool World*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104009/combined)

From wikipedia:

> *Cool World is a 1992 American live-action/animated film directed by Ralph Bakshi, and starring Kim Basinger, Gabriel Byrne, and Brad Pitt. It tells the story of a cartoonist who finds himself in the animated world he created, and is seduced by one of his characters, a comic strip vamp who wants to be real.*

Unfortunately, I don't know how you would locate DVDs from other regions, though IMDB shows a lot of South American distributors.

Comment: Good suggestion, but not the one. I'm sure mine was foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be [Monkeybone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0166276/) with Brendan Fraser which is the story of an animator who gets dragged into the animated world to go up against his chaotic creation.

From IMDB: In a coma, a cartoonist finds himself trapped within his own underground creation and must find a way to get back, while racing against his popular but treacherous character, Monkeybone.

Comment: Another interesting suggestion, but too recent and not a foreign language movie.

Comment: Sorry, in both cases I entirely missed the Foreign language part.